# How can I detect when any file changes under a directory in AIR?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, file, air, directory

I've seen examples that use a timer, get the file list, and check each file for changes, but is there a simpler way to do this such as...

```
<mx:FileSystemList id="fs" visible="false" />

private function onCreationComplete():void
{
    fs.directory = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('../../assets');
    if (fs.directory.exists)
      addEventListener(FileEvent.DIRECTORY_CHANGE, onDirectoryChange);
}

private function onDirectoryChange(e:FileEvent):void
{
    trace("file was changed");
}
```

This doesn't seem to fire when a file changes

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileMonitor class.

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/03/11/monitoring-file-changes-in-adobe-air/

Code from the tutorial:

```
import com.adobe.air.filesystem.FileMonitor;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.adobe.air.filesystem.events.FileMonitorEvent;

private var monitor:FileMonitor;

private function onSelectButtonClick():void
{
    var f:File = File.desktopDirectory;
    f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
    f.browseForOpen("Select a File to Watch.");
}

private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void
{
    var file:File = File(e.target);

    if(!monitor)
    {
        monitor = new FileMonitor();
        monitor.addEventListener(FileMonitorEvent.CHANGE, onFileChange);
        monitor.addEventListener(FileMonitorEvent.MOVE, onFileMove);
        monitor.addEventListener(FileMonitorEvent.CREATE, onFileCreate);
    }

    monitor.file = file;
    monitor.watch();
}

private function onFileChange(e:FileMonitorEvent):void
{
    trace("file was changed");
}

private function onFileMove(e:FileMonitorEvent):void
{
    trace("file was moved");
}

private function onFileCreate(e:FileMonitorEvent):void
{
    trace("file was created");
}
```

Comment: yes. i know that method. it uses a timer and checks the file and it only supports one file.

Comment: Geeze I never even looked in the source of the FileMonitor class, and you're right it does use a timer. That's pretty ridiculous. Unfortunately I think you're out of luck, unless you write a native executable that can actually monitor the file system and interact with it using the native process API's in AIR.

Comment: However I must also note that most likely native solutions will also include some kind of timer functionality, or will need to receive an event, an event which is also generated by some kind of timer functionality. The reason for this is simply the nature of executable processes. They can always be boiled down to essentially an infinite loop which allows and checks against state changes.

Comment: AIR 3 will allow native executables, i.e. DLL for Windows. Hang in there, should be out early October.

Comment: I think you're confused xLite. AIR 3 will allow bundled runtime, so you can bundle the AIR runtime into your executable installer package. AIR 2.0 already allows you to run native executables from actionscript.